# Ruby on Rails rolify creates new roles instead of reusing current roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, rolify

I'm using rolify cancan and devise gem with ROR. I'm currently trying to add 3 types of roles admin, employer and employee. When I execute the following commands:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role("employee")
```

The role gets created and added however if I repeat the steps with a new user it creates a the second user with a new role. Should it not use the same role?

[image]

Here is the code:
**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  rolify
  
  extend Devise::Models
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :fullname, presence: true

  has_many :posts
  has_many :applications
  has_many :users, through: :applications
  has_one_attached :image

  has_many :employee_reviews, class_name: "EmployeeReview", foreign_key: "employee_id"
  has_many :employer_reviews, class_name: "EmployerReview", foreign_key: "employer_id"

  def employer?
      has_role?(:employer)
  end

  def employee?
    has_role?(:employee)
  end 

end
```

**Role.rb**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  
  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true
  

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

Comment: I feel like you have to create a record and only then add role to it. Instead, you will get role with resource_type = NULL like at your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

To set the role as employee and not recreate use the followig steps

user = User.find(1)
user.add_role(:employee)